# Сменить index.php на другой файл nginx, vagrant, laravel homestead

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, homestead

Есть проект на симфони, который хочется развернуть в homestead laravel.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что у данного проекта не index.php а app.php.  Сервер не может найти файл для запуска.

> No input file specified.

При переименовании на index.php - вроде запускается.  Так же присутствует .htaccess, который почему то не считывается, так как в нем все перенаправления на app.php есть.

Как правильно настроить nginx в vagrant?
Возможно это как то настроить в Homestead.yaml?

`app.php app_dev.php` - это уже я дописал, но не помогло.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name xxx;
    root "/home/vagrant/projects/xxx/web/";

    index index.html index.htm index.php app.php app_dev.php;

    charset utf-8;



    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxx-ssl-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    # DEV
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }



    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try_files означает, что сервер попробует найти файл совпадающий с путём в запросе, если не найдёт, то запросит index.php.

Для index.php есть специальное правило -- передать обработку в fpm.

Соответственно, поменяв index.php на app.php, вы добьётесь желаемого.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;

...

location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
```

Можно завести свой nginx-конфиг для этого проекта и написать скрипт его установки. Я не могу дать рабочий рецепт, но в интернете есть например такое [решение](https://medium.com/@maxxscho/laravel-homestead-with-custom-nginx-configurations-2e0fda4ba7dc).

UPD: Решение в статье, кажется немного устарело. Но идея должна сработать. В [папке со скриптами](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/tree/master/scripts/site-types) для разных типов сайтов можно разместить собственный (скопируйте какой-нибудь из существующих). Скрипт должен выполниться, если тип проекта в конфиге совпадает с именем скрипта.

Comment: Спасибо! Завтра попробую.

Comment: @Pavel кстати, судя по наличию htaccess, это apache-проект. Что если сконфигурировать его с типом apache?

Comment: поставил app.php теперь он обращается верно, но не запускает этот файл а скачивает. Попробую везде поменять

Comment: Проблему вроде решил, правда не с помощью конфига. Поставил тип сайта апач - вагрант какие то пакеты докачал, и похоже начал понимать htaccess. Причем обратно потом поменял на symfony4 -  все работает